# Error switching wireless network using netsh

Tags: wireless-networking

I am trying to fetch data from a .bat file to network configuration.but i get the error:

> object already exists.

```
@ECHO off
cls
:start
ECHO.
ECHO 1. Change Connection1 Static IP 
ECHO 2. Change Connection2 Static IP 
ECHO 3. Change Connection3 Static IP 
ECHO 4. Obtain an IP address automatically
ECHO 5. Exit
set choice=
set /p choice=Type the number to print text.
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto con1
if '%choice%'=='2' goto con2
if '%choice%'=='3' goto con3
if '%choice%'=='4' goto autosearch
if '%choice%'=='5' goto end
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid, try again
ECHO.
goto start
:con1
ECHO Connecting Connection 1
netsh interface ip set address "Wireless Network Connection" static 10.35.1.214 255.255.0.0 10.35.1.6
goto end

:con2
ECHO Connecting Connection 2
netsh interface ip set address "Wireless Network Connection" static 10.35.1.221 255.255.0.0 10.35.1.6
goto end

:con3
ECHO Connecting Connection 3
netsh interface ip set address "Wireless Network Connection" static 10.35.1.234 255.255.0.0 10.35.1.6
goto end

:autosearch
ECHO obtaining auto IP
ipconfig /renew "Wireless Network Connection"
goto end

:bye
ECHO BYE
goto end

:end
```

Comment: i don't know netsh that well but it looks like it's trying to set an address not fetch data.. You could troubleshoot..  put pauses in and see if it's a netsh line causing the issue.. remove the echo off.  And then change your question to why does the netsh line fail. or the whatever line. Find the actual line that causes that error and then think about why.

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the address you need to

```
netsh interface ip delete address
```

on the interface